# Replace function not working for long query in ORACLE/PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I have tried running replace Function for long query probably length greater than 4000, the function returns an error of

> ORA-01704:String literal too long.

Is there any other alternative of using Replace function to replace a character in Oracle SQL?

Query:

```
Select REPLACE('VERY_LONG_QUERY','''','''''') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Separating the long query into smaller subqueries and then putting them together again after the replacement?

Comment: Oracle has a hard limit of 4000 bytes for a character literal in SQL. Inside a  PL/SQL block (which is not what you show in your question - that's plain SQL) you can handle character literals up to 32k

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it works in 11g or which is your Oracle version, but this works for me in 12c (Tried from Sql developer latest version ). 
To use `BIND` variables to assign the long string and then run your sql query

```
VARIABLE VERY_LONG_QUERY VARCHAR2(32767);
EXEC :VERY_LONG_QUERY := 'select * from something...........greater than 4000';
Select REPLACE(:VERY_LONG_QUERY,'''','''''') FROM DUAL;
```

Similarly it should work fine if I am doing this in PL/SQL.

Comment: It is not working in my sqldeveloper with Oracle 11g rather it gives me an error of ORA-01460- "unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested"

Comment: @Saman : yes until u upgrade to 12 c and use latest sql developer, splitting is your only option